# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' parent constructor error while extending class

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, class, request

I am trying to extend my class based views from a baseView for my custom admin Section.
The following is a view for the dashboard section.

```
class Dashboard(BaseAdminView):

    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'admin/pages/dashboard.html', {'hello': 'World'})
```

Similarly, the following is the base admin view which I'll be extending for almost all of the related view classes.

```
class BaseAdminView(View):
    loggedInUser = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        if (request.session['loggedInAdministrator'] is None):
            return redirect('adminlogin')
        else:
            loggedInUser = request.session['loggedInAdministrator']
```

My issue is that I am getting `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'` error in the console when I try to access the dashboard.

Isn't `self` then `request` the order of variables here or am I missing something. Also I removed `self` still the issue was the same. If I opt out of using request variable, the constructor works fine though, but using sessions is my only need for which I am doing this in the first place.

How do I make this work?? How do I access request in the parent class??

Also I see that

```
def __init__(self, request):
    super().__init__(request)
```

this code in the dashboard is unnecessary, as the base constructor gets called even if I remove this. Is this how it works? Fairy new to the language and framework..

Addition: `urls.py` in concerned app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='adminhome'),
    path('login', views.Login.as_view(), name='adminlogin'),
    path('logout', views.Logout.as_view(), name='adminlogout')
]
```

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py` code please? This code you shared looks fine.

Comment: @Hagyn hey there, just added my urls.py from the concerned app.

Comment: How do you create your class instances? Please edit your post so that we can re-create your error.

Comment: I simply create various filename.py files within a views folder. eg `dashboard.py` being the above mentioned Dashboard class and `base.py` being the above BaseAdmin class. Then I export them from __init__.py as  `from .dashboard import Dashboard`. Just the standard thing and the `urls.py` as posted. @DocDriven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question you need to implement some action related to `request` object Before you entered to request method handler like `GET/POST` in your `view`, behind the scene, at the `__init__()` method you don't received any `request object`, as you can see if you add `*args` and `**kwargs` to **init**, there was empty in your view classes.

You **shouldn't be overriding** `__init__()`. The request object is first available in the dispatch() method, which is called immediately after `__init__()`, but you shouldn't need to override that method either. Its primary purpose is to call the `get()`, `post()` or other relevant method handlers. Generally speaking, however, it's not necessary to override those either.

If you really absolutely must catch the request at the earliest point possible though, then the dispatch method is your best bet.

Your `BaseAdminView` class seems like this:

```
class BaseAdminView(View):
    loggedInUser = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.session['loggedInAdministrator'] is None:
            return redirect('adminlogin')
        else:
            self.loggedInUser = request.session['loggedInAdministrator']
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and `Dashboard` class seems like this:

```
class Dashboard(BaseAdminView):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'admin/pages/dashboard.html', {'hello': 'World'})
```

Comment: I prefer to use method or class decorator before GET method in these cases, Because it can be more usability and I can choose that which method to applied on it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Had no idea about the dispatch method. Cheers.